# How to give correct reference to Spring service who has acronym class name?

Tags: java, spring

I have a service named "XMLService" and I want to give a reference to this service. What is the correct ref name for acronym? Is "xmlService" is correct?

My Bean;

```
<bean id="xmlExecutorJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="xmlService" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="saveXMLData" />
</bean>
```

My Service;

```
@Service
public class XMLService{
   public void saveXMLData(){
      ....
   }    

}
```

**EDIT:** When I run above code it gives;

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'xmlService' is defined
```

When I update ref value to "xMLService" still gives error;

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'xMLService' is defined
```

Comment: `ref="xmlService"` means: "Take `<bean .../>` with id `xmlService` "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use component scan / beans autodetection, you can explicitly define the bean name using the `value` attribute of the `@Service` annotation:

```
     @Service("xmlService")
     public class XMLService{
```

Otherwise, the bean name is what you have defined in the beans XML.

Comment: Yes I use autodetection but It gives "No bean named 'xmlService' is defined" exception.

Comment: Can you please try defining the bean name in the annotation? I.e. `@Service("xmlService")`

Comment: Yes it is working with custom name but still I don't know what is default name for this service

Answer (score 1):

The correct acronym is the one you name it.

```
<bean id="xmlService" class="your.package.XMLService">
     <property name="anyDependency" ref="dependencyId" />
</bean>
```

Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I am getting "No bean named 'xmlService' is defined" exception.

Comment: you should put the code I gave you (with the right properties, if any) before the xmlExecutorJob bean

Comment: I use <context:component-scan base-package="*" /> for autodetection. Is there any other way without defining a custom bean?